connecting database with laravel --> postman doesnt display data
my api.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user',function (Request $request)
{
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('register',[UserController::class,'register']);


my UserController.php is bellow
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    function register(Request $req)
    {
        return "Hellooooo";
        //return $req->input();
    }
}

my problem is
http://localhost:8000/api/register
above url is not displaying "Hellooo" in POSTMAN (i use post method)
can someone please help
bellow is the output in postman
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/198088083604203600/
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/198088083604203605/



Pretty sure controller methods should not just return a text value ... You should rather be returning a view, as explained here, https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/controllers#basic-controllers

i am following a tutorial & in the tutorial returning a string was demonstrated. Isnt there any other way to test POSTMAN cus im a beginner ..so dont know how to return a view

Can u show what r u receiving as a response?

@Deelliiee , check whether you have used correct  method and url in POSTMAN. Check php artisan route:list to see if Route is available.Use public before function register(Request $req).Finally clear cache using  this command php artisan cache:clear.Check all this and let me know.

Subha   sorry nothing changes. some HTML code is displayed in POSTMAN I use POST method

And that HTML code says what, exactly?

You are using a POST request on a get route?

@Deelliiee you mostly have a structured html response (debugger and other tool) if you click on "preview" in postman, you will see the desired return. Another way is to tell the server that you expect a json response: In your postman add the header Accept with value application/json (instead of the already present one */*

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

@N69S is right. When laravel responds with a HTML page you are most usually missing the Accept header with the value application/json, otherwise you would also see the 404 error as JSON. To @CBroe : As this is in the api routes, you don't expect to reply with a view.

I tried to add this "application/json" to "Accept" in "Header" but it is not editable in POSTMAN ???

can someone please help....can someone plesae put a proper youtube tutorial to create s web app using react js, laravel and mysql pls?
